# How to Remove or delete item from Array on change in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, onchange

Here I want to remove selected item from array when I changed dropdown.
I have few item in checkbox list and  onselect I am pushing item in array but when I change dropdown then selected item should be removed from array.
I have reproduced my issue on here,Please have a look on this link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rhkz6i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: so after resetting the  selectedGroups on changing the option, do you want to get get the selected checkboxes back once you re-select the same option. ?

Comment: Yes, if it is possible please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add `this.selectedGroups = [];` in your `setGroup` function so it can be reset

```
setGroup(nav:any, index){this.selectedGroups = [];}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to reset `this.selectedGroups`. So inside `setGroup(nav:any, index)`, add a line with `this.selectedGroups = []`